# How to implement LoginActivity in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement the premade `LoginActivity` in Android Studio to no avail. I'm stuck in the file *LoginDataSource.java*. Below is the class in it's entirety.

```
public class LoginDataSource {
    
    public Result<LoggedInUser> login(final String username, final String password) {

        try {
            String url = "http://192.168.1.10:1234/my/api";
            
            // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
            RequestQueue requestQueue;

            // Instantiate the cache
            Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024); // 1MB cap

            // Set up the network to use HttpURLConnection as the HTTP client.
            Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());

            // Instantiate the RequestQueue with the cache and network.
            requestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);

            requestQueue.start();

            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Log.i("Response:", response);
                            // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                            // textView.setText("Response is: " + response.substring(0, 500));
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // textView.setText("That didn't work!");
                    Log.e("Error:", error.toString());
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("user", username);
                    params.put("pass", password);

                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return params;
                }
            };

            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

            LoggedInUser fakeUser =
                    new LoggedInUser(
                            java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                            "John Doe");
            return new Result.Success<>(fakeUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new Result.Error(new IOException("Error logging in", e));
        }
    }

    public void logout() {
        // TODO: revoke authentication
    }
}
```

`getCacheDir()` gets highlighted with red and the reason states `Cannot resolve method 'getCacheDir' in 'LoginDataSource'`. I tried changing the parameter to `context.getCacheDir()` but there's no `context` available in the file and I can't import one from anywhere.

What am I doing wrong here? This is driving me insane.

Comment: I agree that the inline code is good, but I think that if you use this style of code here, you lost contact on what is happening. In another word, it is a bad code in my opinion because is difficult to read. Can you try to create a specific object for your Response.Listener and pass the concreate object as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getCacheDir() has to be invoked on a Context object, so you need to pass in a Context into to login. So change login to login(final String username, final String password, final Context context)
and then invoke context.getCacheDir()

Comment: Thanks Don Ha, your reply guided me to the right direction. I successfully managed to implement the `stringRequest` by passing a `Context` object all the way from the component which started the login activity.

However one problem still remains. The `Result<LoggedInUser>`-function in this file always returns the "fakeUser" created at the end of it . It does not wait for the result of the `StringRequest`. How should I refactor the function to wait for the result?

Comment: Your login method makes asynchronous request, so you may not be able to retrieve the result and return to the caller like it is synchronous. This post may have some relevant instructions for you to refactor it https://bugsdb.com/_en/debug/169a7cd2b20ba2908ca4ad5722305e85